# Android Room Database Nested Object Reference for array of objects

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-room

I have a class structure with

```
Class x { 
    int a;
    int b;
    Y[] yList;
}
Class Y {
    int m;
    int n;
}
```

I am using data binding, Room and Dagger. I am getting compilation error as *'cannot find class DatabindingComponent'*, possibly because Room doesn't allow persistent of Nested objects. To enable I used ***@Embedded*** annotation but still getting same error. But if I use ***@Ignore*** annotation indicating Room that do not process this field; compilation is happening successfully.

---

### How to reference nested array of objects for Room Database without foreign key?

---

Please refer to 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#no-object-references
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Ignore.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to reference nested array of objects for Room Database without foreign key?

If you do not want `Y` to be an `@Entity` with its own table, the only option that I know of is to use `@TypeConverters`:

- Define two `static` methods with `@TypeConverter` that convert `Y[]` to and from some basic type (e.g., `String`, by using JSON)
- Register the class holding those methods using `@TypeConverters` somewhere (e.g., on your `RoomDatabase` subclass)

This works using collection classes (e.g., `List`, `Set`). I would guess that it works with Java arrays (`Y[]`), though I have not tried it.

Comment: Nice Solution. But is there any practical example for this.

Comment: @nauman: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#type-converters) covers `@TypeConverter`. [My book on the Architecture Components](https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch) covers `@TypeConverter`. And [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.1/Trips/RoomConverters) from that book demonstrates a few `@TypeConverters`, including going between a `Set<String>` and a `String` via JSON.